# Is there a way to set individual label link colors in JFreeChart's PiePlot?

Tags: java, pie-chart, jfreechart

I see that I can use `setLabelLinkPaint()` to universally apply a color to *all* label links, but I'm looking to set each individual label link to a different color. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I don't see any support for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like for now the most straightforward way to approach this problem is to subclass the `PiePlot` class and override the `drawRightLabel` and `drawLeftLabel` methods. In my case, I needed to have the label link color match the corresponding pie chart section, so in my overridden methods I set `g2.setPaint(getSectionPaint(record.getKey()))`.

My advice to anyone trying to do something similar is to watch out for casting errors if casting from a `JFreeChart` chart object. You will likely have to additionally subclass `ChartFactory` and modify it so that it uses your subclassed `PiePlot` and not the original one.